# How can I change default file name Xcode simulator screenshots?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Default name of Xcode simulator screenshots is `~/Desktop/Simulator Screen Shot - iPhone 8 Plus - YYYY-MM-SS at HH.MM.SS.png`.

But I need file name without whitespace, so I have to change their name manually.

Do you know how can I change default name of them?

I use Xcode 9.3.1 and MacOS 10.13.4

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch the Terminal and type the following command, replacing **NewName** with the file name you wish to use for your screen shot names

   `defaults write com.apple.screencapture name "NewName"`
2. Now restart SystemUIServer by killing it from the command line

   `killall SystemUIServer`
3. Take a screen shot to confirm the file name has been changed from default to the custom name

Only new screen shots will be effected by this change, existing screenshot file names will remain the same.

Once the change has taken effect, all new screenshots will adopt the new name, and additional captures will be sequenced just as before so they don’t overwrite one another.

FYI. This is not tested, Just try and let me know it is working or not.

**UPDATE**

If you want to restore to the default naming convention of screen shot files created in Mac OS X, use the instructions below.

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture name "Screen Shot"
```

Again restart SystemUIServer by killing it

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: is there any way we can revert the newName to the old pattern?

though the above command is not working, just tested out of curiosity.

Comment: Please find updated answer, I tested it and it is working of mac os x screenshots

Comment: This is name I got, NewName 2018-05-17 at 10.39.52 AM, just taken recently :) Please try again

Comment: it's working when I am taking the system screenshots, not for simulator!!

Comment: how to take system screenshots? I am just press command + S with opening simulator

Comment: cmd+shift+3 and cmd+shift+4, this is used to get system screenshot